# How to set specific ID for server controls in an ASP.NET Web Form that is using a MasterPage?

Tags: asp.net, servercontrols

Is it possible to set a specific ID on an ASP.NET server control? Everytime I assign an ID and run the web form the ID changes.

For Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Gets translated into this:

```
<input id="ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName" type="text" />
```

I think this is do to me using master pages, but if so how can I be sure a control will have a certain ID(for javascript purposes). I placed the auto-generated id in my javascript and it is working, but I would prefer to have used the id's that I originally assigned them. Is this possible?

(This is for version:ASP.NET 3.5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way web controls ID's are in .NET prior to version 4.0. Version 4.0 introduces client IDs, which you can read about [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

You can use somthing like this in your JS:

```
var something = '<%= txtName.ClientID %>';
```

Answer (score 29):

Starting with .NET 4 you have greater control about how the client-side IDs look like ([see this post for details](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)).

To force a specific client-side ID, you have to set the ClientIDMode to static. The following will render an `<input>` element with `id="txtName"`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Although if you do this, you have to ensure that you don't have two controls with identical client-side IDs. Check the article linked above for other options.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property in your codebehind to get the actual id after it's been added to the control tree.

Super annoying choice made by the asp.net webforms people.