# Change visibility of a <li> True/False C# MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Project with Master Page c#

i want to change the visibility (True / False) of a `<li>` in a `<div>` programmatically.

master_page

```
<div id="div_admin">
  <ul>
    <li style="margin-left:-30px; margin-bottom:5px" id="li_soli">Soli</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

master_page C#

```
If(listParametro.Count(); > 0){
    <li> need to go Visible False
} else {
    <li> need to go Visible true
}
```

The problem would be how to call the LI object through its ID to change its visibility

Comment: @PeterB thnx! Works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<li runat="server">`, and then you can do `li_soli.Visible = whatever you like`.

Note that this will change the `id` that it gets in the browser to a generated (derived) id value. There are workarounds to deal with that issue, see e.g. here: [How to set specific ID for server controls in an ASP.NET Web Form that is using a MasterPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3304478/1220550)

Comment: I think id will need to change to ID too

Answer (score -1):

You can also use asp.net panel to hide and show

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
  <li> need to go Visible False
  </asp:Panein ll>

 <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="false">
  <li> need to go Visible 
  </asp:Panel>
```

In page load method you can write your condition according to you need.